# Can I use the new Xcode 4.2 Developer Preview to publish regular apps now?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, app-store

Making the long story short: if I download and install the new Xcode 4.2 Developer Preview on my Mac and start developing new iOS 5 apps, can I still using it for developing and releasing iOS 4.x apps?

I do not have the possibility to install two different versions of this platform right now.
Probably someone amongst you has tried it and can answer.

The [iOS 5 beta Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5/index.html) link associated to the new Xcode version seems to be broken.

Thank you!

Comment: There is an answer from an Apple employee at https://devforums.apple.com/thread/102157?tstart=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only submit to the app store with the official releases of the tools, not the betas.

See also Jano's comment above, on the [dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/102157?tstart=0) it has been confirmed that you can't use the beta tools.

Unless you're chronically short on disc space, you can use disk tool to resize your current partition and do a new OS install on a second partition that you then install all the beta tools onto. (You can also do an OS install onto a removable firewire drive.)

I prefer to keep all the beta tools on a complete separate OS installation, as then there's no danger at all that I'll end up a state when I can't publish apps, and publishing apps is what makes me money.

Comment: Does Xcode let you install various versions on a single OS X installation? I tried with the old Xcode 3 and I have been able to do such a thing only with Xcode 3 + Xcode 4 beta ...

Comment: Nevermind ... I misunderstood your answer. I do not have that much space right now. If I can't publish updates, that's weird. On the Apple website I can't find anything about this.

Comment: Yes, you can do that as far as I know. You'll probably also need to install a beta of itunes. I prefer to keep all the beta releases well away from the OS installation I use to make money.