# Can't build iOS app with Xcode 7 beta

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader, swift2, xcode7

The new Xcode 7 beta was released and I decided to build an iOS app in it. Now I have finished building the application in Swift 2.0. I just finished uploading the binary when it hit me. You can't develop apps for other than beta versions of iOS with a beta version of Xcode - and since I built the app in Swift 2.0, I cannot compile it with a previous version of Xcode and upload a build that way.

Is there any way that I can get the application out, or do I have to wait until apple releases a released version of Xcode 7 with Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to wait until Apple start accepting XCode beta 7 Apps (This will be a date near to the software public release), all of this in order to prevent your app of crashing in old devices. You can only submit to the app store with the official releases of the tools, not the betas.

Have your tried archiving your app and uploading with `Application loader`?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried uploading with the Application loader, but I'm getting the same result. Aparently the information about the Xcode version is stored in the archive.

Comment: That confirms that you will have to wait to official release. Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265754/can-i-use-the-new-xcode-4-2-developer-preview-to-publish-regular-apps-now

Comment: I see, thank you. I opened the project in an earlier version on Xcode and fixed the programming from Swift 2.0 to Swift - Luckily, the only thing I had to change was to remove some ! and I had to re-write the error handling.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck using the Xcode_7_GM_seed.dmg "release"? I'm not able to see/select my build in iTunes Connect! I've also just tried building with XCode7 and using Application Loader to upload, and am currently waiting for propagation or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue ... make sure your distribution provisioning profile is for the app store and not for ad hoc or enterprise distribution :)